# In an open belt drive, which angle of wrap should be taken for calculating tension in the belt?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pulleys, machine-design

An open belt drive with flat belt has different angle of wrap on the larger and smaller pulley. I have to calculate a tension in the pulley. We generally use the formulae
[image: Formulae]

Here θ is the angle of wrap. Now the angle of wrap is different for larger pulley and smaller pulley in the belt drive. So which angle of wrap should be used in this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the product of angle of wrap (θ) and coefficient of friction (μ) of the corresponding pulley. Whichever product is less that angle of wrap is considered.

In case the coefficient of friction is same for both the pulleys in open-belt drive system, angle of wrap of the smaller pulley is usually considered.

In case of crossed-belt drive system, angle of wrap is same for both smaller as well as larger pulley so the smaller coefficient of friction is considered in the formulae.[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: use the angle on the driver/driving/primary  pulley**

---

It depends on which pulley is giving the motion. On a pulley you have a *tight* and a *slack* side.

[image]

**figure 1: Slack and tight side [smlease](https://www.smlease.com/entries/mechanism/what-is-belt-drives-type-advantages-and-disadvantages/)**

On the slack side is $T_2$ and on the Tight side is $T_1$. The distribution is presented below:

[image]

**Figure 2: Tension distribution -notice that the rotation is opposite to the image above - (source : [tec-science](https://www.tec-science.com/mechanical-power-transmission/belt-drive/maximum-belt-stress/))**

So the angle should be taken on the driving(driver) pulley.

---

**Note**: the second diagram has a less than optimal configuration. It should be upside down. I.e. the slack side be on the top. The reason is that this improves the angle, and the overall traction of the belt on the pulley.

Comment: Hi. I have read it on the following link that the product of coefficient of friction and angle of wrap should be considered for such cases. Whichever product is less, that angle of wrap should be considered for the tension ratio formulae. Link: http://www.engineering108.com/Data/Engineering/Mechanical/Design_of_Machine_Elements/Module13/mod13les1.pdf If the coefficient of friction is same for both pulleys, then I think smaller pulley will have less angle of wrap and it should be considered for calculation.

Comment: Shigley Mechanical engineering design, at chapter 17-2 Flat- Round-Belt Drives p883-884, describes Firbank's (Mechanics of the Flat Belt Drive) theory. It states that the  "*angle of contact is made up of the effective arc through which power is transmitted, and the idle arc.*". Usually, the driving pulley one, is the smaller one (which is in accordance to your reference).

Comment: @AshishMutekar I have rejected your edit because it was not aligned with my original answer. I think the best course of action is to can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice.